# Why is every file marked as an executable on my mounted NTFS partition?

Tags: linux, partitioning, fstab

I have edited my `/etc/fstab` file to include this line:

`/dev/sda5 /media/yannbane/Shared ntfs defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0 0`

I did this so my `dev/sda5` partition (labeled `Shared`) is automatically mounted on system startup.

However, when I navigate to `/media/yannbane/Shared`, and search for some files - all of them are marked green (executable as per my `l`, which is an alias of `ls -CF`).

[image]

You can see that png files, js files, txt files, html files, css files, save files - everything, is marked as executable.

Why is this so? Do I need to change some `fstab` settings?

I am using Linux Mint w/ Cinnamon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `umask=007` to `fmask=117` (or perhaps `fmask=117,dmask=007`). The `umask` option sets the permission bits to be removed from both files and directories, while `fmask` sets it for ordinary files and `dmask` sets it for directories. Since you specified `0` for both the owner and the group, that means that *no* permissions were removed for files or directories, so the execute permission was left intact for the owner and the group. Explicitly removing execute permissions on files by using `1` instead of `0` and `fmask` instead of `umask` will fix the problem. Execute permissions are normally included on directories, so you don't want to remove them.

Comment: OK, will do, but will this unable me from executing files I actually want to execute?

Comment: Yes; but you shouldn't be storing Linux executables on an NTFS volume, except perhaps as a temporary transfer measure. NTFS just wasn't designed with Unix/Linux-style permissions and ownership in mind and so is unsuitable for storing files that require those features.

Comment: Oh OK. I won't be storing any executables there then.

Comment: But what if I *need* to store Linux executables there, because I use NTFS partition as a partition shared by Linux and Windows? I don't want *all* files to be executable (because they're mostly source code text files and resources which *have to* be seen by Windows and Linux). I only need the Linux executables (compiled from these sources on Linux) be marked as executable when seen by Linux (and only these files, no else) to be able to compile and run them from there without the need to copy to some other partition. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: SasQ, your "need" to do something doesn't make it possible. I might need to get from Boston to Los Angeles in five minutes, but it isn't going to happen. That said, I recently heard of a possible solution. See http://jp-andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/advanced-ntfs-3g.html for details. This is "bleeding-edge" software that might or might not work. It could end up trashing your whole disk. Personally, I wouldn't try it in a production environment. Instead, I'd find another way to accomplish my goals.